# Is there a symbol that will yield the beginning of the mapping of the executable in the process?

Tags: linker, ld, elf

By printing out `/proc/self/maps`, I can see that the executable is mapped beginning at `0x00400000`, but I was wondering if there was a way to get this programmatically without having to parse the `/proc/self/maps`.